# TBB on Windows XP (using in OpenCV) - error entry point InitializeCriticalSectionEx

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, tbb

I tried to compile TBB which I want to use on OpenCV. I am using Windows XP and Visual Studio 2010 C++. When I compiled TBB 4.4 I got the error

*"The procedure entry point InitializeCriticalSectionEx could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll."*

The error is similar but under little different conditions like here:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/6151/opencv_createsamplesexe-entry-point-problem-with-xp/

In my case I cannot run the program at all. I tried the solution described there, so I renamed InitializeCriticalSectionEx to InitializeCriticalSection and removed parameter 2 and 3.

OpenCV claimes the bug is not on their side. I know OpenCV uses this:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
        InitializeCriticalSectionEx(&cs, 1000, 0);
#else
        InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
#endif
```

I know this should not make any problems but I commented some lines to keep InitializeCriticalSection(&cs); only. I recompiled the OpenCV and still the same error. Finally I have found in TTB:
tbb44_20160627oss\include\tbb\machine\windows_api.h

```
__TBB_WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI TryEnterCriticalSection( LPCRITICAL_SECTION );
__TBB_WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount( LPCRITICAL_SECTION, DWORD );
// Overloading WINBASEAPI macro and using local functions missing in Windows XP/2003
#define InitializeCriticalSectionEx inlineInitializeCriticalSectionEx
```

I also find the word "InitializeCriticalSectionEx" in opencv_core310d.dll and opencv_core310.dll. Does the overload really work and why I got the error? How could I fix it?

Update:
the definition in OpenCV

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT           // This is needed for the declaration of TryEnterCriticalSection in winbase.h with Visual Studio 2005 (and older?)
  #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686857(VS.85).aspx
#endif
```

Comment: You need to identify the module that refers to this function. Is it OpenCV. If so then you'll need to find a version that supports XP.

Comment: *"When I compiled TBB 4.4 I got the error"* - That's fairly fuzzy. You certainly didn't get that error during compiling, but at some other point after that. When? If this was during runtime, did you inspect the callstack? Did you set up your debugger to break, when an exception is thrown (assuming that TBB uses exceptions to report errors)?

Comment: Thx for ur answer. I hav commented d lines out in OpenCV so it couldnt create problem - check my post update - should be 0x0400. I have also commended out the overloading directive in TBB. I recompiled all & now this error was solved. I have different error but this error is definitively solved. I did not try exception and did not watch call back. When I open one of my project using OpenCV, I press F10 to join into main function & it prints d error. The current error - entry point error - is probably because the current program cannot find the tbb_debug.dll so I will check all paths.

Comment: The `#ifndef` part means your definition will only be used if the symbol has not already been defined. If it has, then your definition will be ignored. You very likely do not want that. If it worked, it worked because the symbol was not already defined, so just remove the `#ifndef` part. Getting a redefinition error here would be a benefit, so you can see that there is a clash about which version is to be targeted.

Comment: It is very problematic to compile the OpenCV so it takes long time. So I will not want to recompile it now when the first error disapeared. The current error is because I did not set the path to TBB dlls and I do not know if should I copy the dll to the folder with opencv dlls or place them separately and set environment variable PATH to the TBB libraries which would mean set path to every library I use. Unlikely

Answer (score 4):

> "The procedure entry point InitializeCriticalSectionEx could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll."

This is a standard error that Windows displays when you try to run a program that contains a statically-bound call to a function in a DLL that does not exist.

The InitializeCriticalSectionEx function is not available on Windows XP, but the version of the library that you have contains code that calls this function.

> OpenCV claimes the bug is not on their side. I know OpenCV uses this:
>
> ```
> #if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
>         InitializeCriticalSectionEx(&cs, 1000, 0);
> #else
>         InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
> #endif
> ```

OpenCV's workaround is a *compile-time* solution. It determines at the point when the library is compiled which version of Windows is being targeted, and uses that information to generate a call to the appropriate version of the function.

There are two possibilities for why this is going wrong in your case:

1. You are using the OpenCV library in binary form, and the binary that you have was compiled to target Windows Vista and later. You can solve this by obtaining the source code for OpenCV and compiling it yourself, either as a DLL or a static library.
2. You are compiling with `_WIN32_WINNT` set to `0x0600` or later. By default, the Windows headers define this symbol to the latest available version. You have to explicitly define an earlier target version if you want it. To arrange for targeting Windows XP, add the following code at the top of your code file (probably in your precompiled header):

   ```
   #include <WinSDKVer.h>
   #define _WIN32_WINNT      _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
   #include <SDKDDKVer.h>
   ```

Comment: `_WIN32_WINNT` is a global setting, and is best passed to the compiler on the command line, to avoid any accidental mismatches.

Comment: My problem is solved after commenting out the TBB directive and OpenCV directives. The program runs without runtime error. Thanks for your time.